# Filling Multiple TextBoxes with ListView Data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, textbox

My script has 20 text boxes for a maximum of 10 Listview Items. There is only one sub-item for each item. My goal is to have these text boxes auto fill for each item added to the ListView.

**Example of the textboxes:**

[image: 1]]

Currently, the script bellow has two **for-loop** statements. The first one will click through all the items in the listview. The second **for** will input the values to the text boxes. I'm unsure how to incorporate a way to have the script fill all the text boxes. I imagine a **case** statement will be used.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For I As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1

        ListView1.Items(I).Selected = True
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox1.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox2.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Any help or ideas is appreciated.

Comment: Can't do much with those loops.  Might as well just have `TextBox1.Text = ListView1.Items(0).Text` etc.  You could get "hacky" if you name your boxes so that you can map them to an index.

Comment: So you have 10 custom objects with 2 properties (atleast) inside listview and you want to populate all textboxes with them? There is 1 question. Is order of populating important?

Comment: @AleksaRistic No, the order populating the text-boxes in not important.

Comment: Is it ok if i write code in c#?

Comment: @AleksaRistic Majority of my code is already in vb.net. Would be preferred if it was in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working response to my question that I managed to create. Please keep in mind that the order of populating the textboxes is not relevant to my issue. I'm sure this code can be shortened somehow and if done I'll mark that response as solved; until then, this is a working alternative.

```
Dim count = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 ' Using ListView1.Items.Count to get max number of rows to prevent error

' Highlight each item
For index As Integer = 0 To count 
    ListView1.Items(index).Selected = True

    ' First Selected Item
    If index = 0 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox1.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox2.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Second Selected Item
    If index = 1 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox3.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox4.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Third Selected Item
    If index = 2 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox5.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox6.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Forth Selected Item
    If index = 3 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox7.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox8.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Fith Selected Item
    If index = 4 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox9.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox10.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Sixth Selected Item
    If index = 5 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox11.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox12.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Seventh Selected Item
    If index = 6 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox13.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox14.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Eighth Selected Item
    If index = 7 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox15.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox16.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Ninth Selected Item
    If index = 8 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox17.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox18.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Tenth Selected Item
    If index = 9 Then

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            OpenModule.TextBox19.Text = item.Text
            OpenModule.TextBox20.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text

        Next

    End If

    ' Deselect Current Item
    ListView1.Items(index).Selected = False
Next
```